# Creating a SOAP proxy?

Tags: c#, web-services, api, soap

I Want to create a SOAP proxy, that modifies the original web service SOAP header, nampespace and keeping the body the same)

What is the best way to do this? Create a SOAP provider , that consumes the original web service then modify the header and namespacs? (this seems like alot of work?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have few SOAP services, your suggestion is the way to go. If you have many SOAP services you want to transform, it might be a better idea to write a `HttpHandler`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5c67a8bd(VS.71).aspx for more information.